# Can't get rid of a persistent Apache2 redirect (even with purge/flush/reinstall)

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I'm absolutely stumped here. I was attempting to forward all http requests to https (so port 80 to 443). I tired a few methods, including

```
Redirect / https:/address.com

Redirect permanent / https://address.com

RedirectRewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It finally took after I tried Redirect permanent, but the forward only half worked (would redirect to proper host but wouldn't serve the page), but when I tried to undo the redirect, it persisted (so still leading to a broken address).

I tried overriding it, tried flushing DNS, completely purged apache2 and reinstalled, and still this redirect persists. I've run out of ideas. It's not just my browser cache either; I've tested on multiple external IP's with the same result.

The .conf with the broken redirect is as follows (Note no redirect is currently active), this conf is no longer active either.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Redirect / https:/address.com

    #Redirect permanent / https://address.com

    #RedirectRewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The only virtual host that's active is the host that I actually want working, which is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName address.com
    ServerAlias www.address.com
    ServerAlias *.address.com

    ServerAdmin webadmin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /disk2/example_site

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile example.key
    SSLCACertificatePath /example/
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And still, the redirect persists.

Comment: how long did you wait? At least an hour is required for many DNS changes to take full effect. You could try re-installing the whole OS.

Comment: It's been 5 days since this issue popped up. I'd really rather not reinstall the OS, as there's a considerable amount of config in it. That's going to be my last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use a permanent redirect.

As you've found removing it from your server does not remove the redirection for any browser which has visited the page. The instruction is *always* cached indefinitely by the browser.

The subsequent rewrite rules mean that you will be supplying an https response to an http request - which is clearly non-sensical.

Add [L,R] to the final line (not R=301 as suggested elsewhere on stack overflow). And if you really are doing away with non-ssl permanently and completely, use HSTS.

(BTW to fix the browsers you'll need to interfere with the cache database directly or delete and reinstall)

Comment: Dang. That's what I get for not doing enough reading. However, each of those methods were tried individually, never simultaneously  the permanent redirect was actually the first thing i tried and it didn't do what it was supposed to, hence the other methods. Can you give me a full example of what it should look like with your modification? Also, what would have to be uninstalled, the each browser that was used or are you referring to server side?

Here's the other thing though - even with the newer configuration active, new browsers are still getting redirected, which is confusing me.

Comment: Any browser which saw the permanent redirect will continue to apply the permanent redirect.

Answer (score 0):

//this should be a comment

this should helps you.

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.your_site_name_here.com/
```

I read, that you try this.
Could you post whole apache config ?

Comment: I edited in the two relevant .conf files. First is the one that is apparently persisting, the second is what should be working and isnt.

Comment: could you post both files to see your actual config ?

Comment: The current actually config is just the second conf. The only changes are to the ServerNames and Alias, which as I've indicated are the same for *:80 and *:443

Answer (score 0):

Remove any reference to permanent redirect either in configuration or in web app, depending on where you did it.

Then, just clear your browser cache **as a whole**. If it doesn't work, clear browser data too.

It's a problem of *client*, not server. Never use 301 or 308 redirect if you are not sure of what you're doing, they'll be cached indefinitely.